# Sequelize wont get table from database

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am setting up Sequelize to make it easier to manipulate an MSSQL database.

I have attempted to define a table named 'Stock', but when I try and query this it does all sorts of weird things.
Here is my code for defining it:

```
const Stock = sequelize.define('Stock', {
    StockID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    TradeName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    ProductGroupID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    ProductClassID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    ClubID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    NettIntoStore: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    NegotiatedCost: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    MaximumSOH: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    OrderCategory: {
        type: Sequelize.SMALLINT
    },
    LastCountDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    RobotStoreInFridge: {
        type: Sequelize.SMALLINT
    },
    NoShelfLabels: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    SOLayby: {
        type: Sequelize.REAL
    },
});

// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
Stock.findOne().then(stock => {
    console.log(stock.get('TradeName'));
});
```

Now running this normally. I.E. getting the first stock row would be easy; but it tires to referrence 'Stocks' in the query for some reason as seen in the code:

[image]

I dont wish to add a new primary ID, that is already set as StockID (I imagine I have to set that myself next to type, but at the moment I simply want to get an existing database (Stock) and simply query it and update certain rows.

Answer (score 1):

**Sequelize will assume your table has a id primary key property by default.**

To define your own primary key:

```
sequelize.define('collection', {
  uid: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true // Automatically gets converted to SERIAL for postgres
  }
});

sequelize.define('collection', {
  uuid: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true
  }
});
```

**[READ MORE](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/advanced/legacy.html#primary-keys)**

Comment: Thus will this mean if I just set the correct primary key it will fetch my already made database instead of attempting to modal a fresh one?

Comment: @Cacoon , Yes why not :)